# How to list the local drives in dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

In my project the dropdown should list all drives in local computer.

### Here is the code: -

```
ddlDrives.Items.Clear();
ddlDrives.Items.Add("-Select-");
foreach (string objDrive in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
{
     ddlDrives.Items.Add(objDrive);
}
```

But if It hosted in server ,Its showing server drives.I just want to show the User' Local system drives. What Should I do?

Comment: I doubt if its possible. You can't access client machine's logical drive using c#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `DriveInfo` Class:-

Try this:-

```
           if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlDrives.Items.Clear();
                ddlDrives.Items.Add("-Select-");
                foreach (var d in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
                {
                    ddlDrives.Items.Add(d.Name);
                }
            }
```